# Finding a string along with a few other words

Tags: python, regex

I have a string (email message) that I need to search and find the word "Downtime:" 8 characters after that word and From: to: timing before the search term.
For e.g.

```
mystring="""
AB\r\n\r\n--_=_swift_v4_13613629825124c026192e8_=_\r\nContent-Type: multipart/related;\r\n  oundary="_=_swift_v4_13613629825124c02620826_=_"\r\n\r\n--_ =_swift_v4_13613629825124c02620826_=_\r\n
From: 2013-01-11 04:26:07, To: 2013-01-11 05:56:08, Downtime: 1h 30m 01s\r\n\r\n
some more text here From: 2013-01-29 04:51:07, To: 2013-01-29 05:41:07, Downtime: 0h 50m 00s\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n This is a scheduled report from If you wish to no longer receive t=\r\nhis report you can unsubscribe by logging in to and u=\r\npdate your email report settings.\r\nCopyright: 2013 
"""
```

Expected result:

```
From: 2013-01-11 04:26:07, To: 2013-01-11 05:56:08, Downtime: 1h 30m 01s
From: 2013-01-29 04:51:07, To: 2013-01-29 05:41:07, Downtime: 0h 50m 00s
```

Comment: I am a little surprised that you haven't posted what you've tried yet...

Comment: @BlackVegetable Same here. As a 5k user, I would expect you to know the site well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex of the form

```
From:\s*[^,]+,\s*To:\s[^,]+,\s*Downtime:[\w ]+
```

Test

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'From:\s*[^,]+,\s*To:\s[^,]+,\s*Downtime:[\w ]+',  mystring)
['From: 2013-01-11 04:26:07, To: 2013-01-11 05:56:08, Downtime: 1h 30m 01s', 'From: 2013-01-29 04:51:07, To: 2013-01-29 05:41:07, Downtime: 0h 50m 00s']
```

Comment: it is wrong match for this case: `"From: 2013-01-11 04:26:07, To: jh2013hdjdh-01-11 05:56:08, Downtime: 1h 30m 01s"`

Answer (score 1):

While nu11p01n73R's answer works (I assume, haven't looked into regex myself), you can do this with string manipulation quite simply.

```
mystring="""AB\r\n\r\n--_=_swift_v4_13613629825124c026192e8_=_\r\nContent-Type: 
multipart/related;\r\n  oundary="_=_swift_v4_13613629825124c02620826_=_"\r\n\r\n--_ 
=_swift_v4_13613629825124c02620826_=_\r\n
From: 2013-01-11 04:26:07, To: 2013-01-11 05:56:08, Downtime: 1h 30m 01s\r\n\r\n
some more text here From: 2013-01-29 04:51:07, To: 2013-01-29 05:41:07, Downtime: 0h 50m 
00s\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n This is a scheduled report from If you wish to no longer receive 
t=\r\nhis report you can unsubscribe by logging in to and u=\r\npdate your email report 
settings.\r\nCopyright: 2013 
"""  #imported from where ever and however

from_loc = mystring.find("From: ")
dtime_right = mystring.find("\r\n",from_loc) #find the end of the line after downtime
msg = mystring[from_loc:dtime_right] #string splicing
```

>>> print msg

From: 2013-01-11 04:26:07, To: 2013-01-11 05:56:08, Downtime: 1h 30m 01s

Note: this can be condensed into 1 line if you want to save on lines for whatever reason:

```
 msg = mystring[mystring.find("From: "):dtime_right = mystring.find("\r\n",from_loc = mystring.find("From: "))]
```

This is *really* messy, and I don't recommend it, but the option's there :P

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 import re
    p = re.compile(ur'from:\s*([0-9\-\s:]+),\s*to:([0-9\-\s:]+),\s*downtime:\s*([0-9\shms]+)', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
    test_str = u"AB\r\n\r\n--_=_swift_v4_13613629825124c026192e8_=_\r\nContent-Type: multipart/related;\r\n oundary=\"_=_swift_v4_13613629825124c02620826_=_\"\r\n\r\n--_ =_swift_v4_13613629825124c02620826_=_\r\n\nFrom: 2013-01-11 04:26:07, To: 2013-01-11 05:56:08, Downtime: 1h 30m 01s\r\n\r\n\nsome more text here From: 2013-01-29 04:51:07, To: 2013-01-29 05:41:07, Downtime: 0h 50m 00s\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n This is a scheduled report from If you wish to no longer receive t=\r\nhis report you can unsubscribe by logging in to and u=\r\npdate your email report settings.\r\nCopyright: 2013 \n"

    re.findall(p, test_str)
```

[live demo](http://regex101.com/r/sE3yD5/1)